# How to redirect to a login-entry-point in a different EAR

Tags: java, spring, redirect, jboss, spring-security

In one of my deployed EARs I have a security context like so:

```
<security:http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login" filters="none" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated() and permitAll" />

    <security:custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="ssoFilter" />
</security:http>
<bean id="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">

    <property name="loginFormUrl" value="/login"/>
</bean>
```

Now in a second EAR I want to redirect to the login page of the first one. Can this be done somehow without extending the `LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint` ?

Because currently if I try an absolute URL in the second EAR security context:

```
<property name="loginFormUrl" value="http://host/ear1ContextPath/login"/>
```

I get redirected to: http://host/ear2contextPath/login.

Which is incorrect.

Thanks

Comment: Can you describe your scenario why you need this?

Comment: @abalogh Single sign on, the first EAR login URL will be the entry point for all other systems.

Comment: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?105771-Integrate-Single-Sign-On-using-Spring-Security -> check this

Comment: @abalogh thanks for the link. I have read the supported SSO solutions, we decided however that they would not fit our current requirements, I might ask another question for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do this by implementing my own `UrlAuthenticationFaliureHandler` and handling the absolute URLs programatically (just do a servlet redirect and then break the filter chain).

Then I could inject the new FailureHandler in my custom filter like this:

```
<bean id="absoluteUrlLoginFailureHandler" class="tld.company.AbsoluteUrlAuthenticationFaliureHandler">

    <property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="http://company.domain.tld/Login.html"/>
</bean>
<bean id="absoluteUrlFilter" class="tld.company.MyUserPassFilter">

    <property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="absoluteUrlLoginFailureHandler"/>            
</bean>
```

And then I set that filter in the namespace configuration:

```
<http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated() and permitAll" />

    <custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="absoluteUrlFilter" />
</http>
```

The `<entry-point-ref>` element seems to handle absolute URLs by default.